# Writing to a file at once or appending a line by line - disk writes

Tags: io, drive

I'm concerned about disc drive life and I'd like to know which way takes minimum amount of writes, so the HDD/SSD won't wear out too soon:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line + '\n')
```

or

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))
    f.write('\n') # just to keep the same content as in the previous example
```

I know HDD drivers have a flushing mechanism, so in theory, both should equally wear the drive out, but I'd like to verify my understanding by asking.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you want to enforce some precautionary actions or not, as long as there's other programs installed in your computer, there's always going to be read/write operation going on and this operation can either leave behind memory leak or not, so there's no way to say you can prevent the hard-drive or SSD from wearing out.

Although if you're more concern about your applications not doing any damage to the HDD/SSD, you can maintain a healthy read/write operation. Usually this kind of operation include making sure any read/write resource is freed or close after any operation is carried out. Avoid writing large data at once into memory, either break it down to the maximum limit allowed by your memory or HDD/SSD read/write cycle and also avoid redundant code that perform repetitive actions on a file such as IO operations running in a looping construct like `for`, `while` and others and if you must have this kind of read/write operation on a loop, have some delay, and ensure the read operation is done and closed or freed after all the reading or writing is complete.